# Bind domain to ip

Tags: domain-name-system

Newbie question.

I want to bind domain name to my vps, then launch BIND server there.

I have made a zone on Hurricane Electric Free DNS, have created A entries for root domain name, ns1 and ns2 subdomains. Also, there has been created CNAME entry for www subdomain.

```
; amiha.ru Dumped Tue Sep 24 21:21:03 2013
;
amiha.ru.   86400   IN  SOA ns1.he.net. hostmaster.he.net. (
                    2013092411  ; Serial
                    10800   ; Refresh
                    1800    ; Retry
                    604800  ; Expire
                    86400 ) ; Minimum TTL
amiha.ru.   86400   IN  NS  ns2.he.net.
amiha.ru.   86400   IN  NS  ns3.he.net.
amiha.ru.   86400   IN  NS  ns4.he.net.
amiha.ru.   86400   IN  NS  ns5.he.net.
amiha.ru.   86400   IN  A   208.115.236.90
ns1.amiha.ru.   86400   IN  A   208.115.236.90
ns2.amiha.ru.   86400   IN  A   208.115.236.90
www.amiha.ru.   86400   IN  CNAME   amiha.ru.
```

After that, I have set he.net DNS-servers on registrar control panel:

[image: registrar control panel]

But when I want now to connect my server, I have an error:

> The dnsserver returned:
>
> Name Server for domain 'amiha.ru' is unavailable.

What is wrong, and what have I do to fix it?

Comment: The he.net NS server don't appear to know about your domain, are you expecting them to?

Comment: @Paul since I have added an A-record "amiha.ru. -> 208.115.236.90" into "amiha.ru" zone, to he.net NS server, I am expecting that the server knows about my domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The registrar for the domain 'amiha.ru' does not yet recognize the nameservers at Hurricane Electric:

```
$ dig +short ns amiha.ru
dns2.yandex.net.
dns1.yandex.net.
```

If you want to use the HE nameservers, your domain registrar will need to recognize them as authoritative for the 'amiha.ru' zone before you can proceed.

Comment: The terminology is: the delegation from the TLD needs to point to the he.net nameservers instead of the yandex ones.  The screenshot of the DNS management panel shows this is already done; probably it is just a matter of waiting for propagation.

Comment: Yes, that's true. This has gotten really fast; registrar changes used to take 24-72 hours to propagate, but (at least with large registrars), I'm regularly seeing changes get made within 15-60 minutes to nameservers around the world.

Comment: Be that as it may, I'm pretty sure that it's the problem.  That, or the changes he made in the control panel didn't take effect because of the registrar being incompetent.

Comment: In any event, the nameservers listed at the registrar and those in the zone file MUST agree. There might be other problems too, but until this is resolved nothing else will work.